# Monitor iPhone's mic level without pausing iPod

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I'm using AVAudioRecorder to get the current level of the microphone, but it pauses any iPod music that's playing and won't let the user unpause it. Is there a way of getting the two to work together?